# Colorized ROC curve with cutoff values greater than one in ROCR package

Tags: r, plot, classification, roc, palette

I have used ROCR package to plot a colorized roc curve. The curve itself does not have any problem and looks nice and fine but the palette shows that cutoff points are greater than 1 which is incorrect as these are probabilities and should be in the range of 0 to 1. I checked my dataset several times but it seems ok and there is nothing wrong with my dataset.

Here is the code along with the predictions values and their corresponding labels.[here is the plotted roc curve for my classification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66RlQ.png)

My initial guess is that there is a bug in the ROCR package but I'm not completely sure. Any help to figure it out would be appreciated.

```
library(ROCR)
labels <-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
scores<-c(1,1,1,0.8,1,1,1,0.95,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.97,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.206,0)
pred<-prediction(scores,labels)
perf<-performance(pred,"tpr","fpr")
plot(perf,colorize=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you found a bug in `ROCR`, caused by the first `cutoff` being `Inf`, which in turn causes the first entry of `alpha.values` to be `Inf` as well:

```
> attributes(pred)$cutoffs[[1]]
[1]   Inf 1.000 0.970 0.950 0.800 0.206 0.000
> attributes(perf)$alpha.values[[1]]
[1]   Inf 1.000 0.970 0.950 0.800 0.206 0.000
```

This would not be a problem so far, but it seems `alpha.values` is used for colourization, which might cause for this strange behaviour. Setting the first entry to `1` instead of `Inf` fixes the issue, which could be use as a quick fix to this problem:

```
> attributes(perf)$alpha.values[[1]][1] <- 1
> attributes(perf)$alpha.values[[1]]
[1] 1.000 1.000 0.970 0.950 0.800 0.206 0.000
> plot(perf,colorize=TRUE)
```

[image: ROC]

Comment: Hi geekoverdose. Thanks, that's right.  It seems reasonable now :)